# Hosted application, DNS server setup?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting, saas

Currently I'm allowing users to have an hosted application. Currently they have to point A-records to our servers (sometimes this is to hard or get's messy). I've seen other players using 2 dns servers, so that the user only needs to change these. I'm willing to implement this, but a lot of questions come up.

- What should I use for this? Can I use bind?
- The records need to be generated from a mysql database
- What type of servers do I need? Is a DNS server taking a lot of load? Currently having around 80K daily visitors.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: How do you mean? This is no homerwork

Comment: No, but it not very clear. For instance, I do not see what are these "2 dns servers". And we do not see if the users have their own domain names or not. You should focus on the problem you try to solve and not mix it with vague solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite confused so I will not try to answer to everything. The important points:

1. Most name servers can take their data from a flat file, in the RFC 1035 "standard zone file format". If the authoritative data is in a MySQL database, that's not a problem: just write a three-lines Perl/Python/Ruby/whetever script which will generate the zone file from the database. Some name servers allow also a direct link to the database but it is very dangerous: you depend on one more component, and for a critical function
2. An authoritative DNS server does not take a lot of load. And 80K daily visitors is peanuts (not even one per second). Any laptop can sustain 20 000 requests per second with fast name servers such as NSD.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you advice to use? Bind9 or something else?

Comment: Depends on many things. If you want a sound advice, explain what you are trying to achieve (as I said, it is not clear for me).